# ¿Cómo hacer TRUNCATE TABLE en sqlite?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Estoy desarrollando una app con sincronización a un servidor, no sé cómo vaciar un tabla de mi sqlite, para luego llenar con nueva info, no sé si me entienda, no quiero eliminar toda la base, y si vuelvo a sincronizar se repiten los datos.

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacer un truncate table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto puede servirte:

```
delete from `TABLE`; 
update sqlite_sequence set seq=0 where name=`TABLE`;
```

En sqlite no hay TRUNCATE. Lo que hacen estas consultas es borrar el contenido de la tabla TABLE y luego inicializar el contador de la tabla.

Comment: Debo ejecutar la consulta con rawquery?

Comment: Esto de que forma vaciaría la tabla???  Esto es para modificar el auto incremento!

Comment: el delete from table elimina todos los elementos; y el update inicializa el contador de autoincremento, como dices. Ya he comentado que no existe un truncate como tal en sqlite. Esto es lo mas parecido que he llegado a usar.

Comment: Para Usarlo deben hacerlo con execSQL